# .getResponseCode() hangs when trying to connect java(blackberry project) to webservice

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, httpconnection

I am trying to connect to a webservice from my blackberry project in eclipse.  My code for URLConnector is the following

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;


public class URLConnector 
{
HttpConnection con = null; 
InputStream is = null; 

public URLConnector()   {
    try 
    {
    Dialog.inform("1"); 
    String url = new String("https://webserviceBlahBlah");

    Dialog.inform(con.toString()); 
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode(); 
        Dialog.inform("3"); 
        if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
            Dialog.inform("3.5"); 
            System.out.println(responseCode); 
        } 
        is = con.openInputStream(); 
        byte[] responseData = new byte[10000]; 
        int length = 0; 
        Dialog.inform("4"); 
        StringBuffer rawResponse = new StringBuffer(); 
        while (-1 != (length = is.read(responseData))) { 
            Dialog.inform("5"); 
            rawResponse.append(new String(responseData, 0, length)); 
        } 
        final String result = rawResponse.toString(); 
        System.out.println(result); 
        Dialog.inform("6"); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        Dialog.inform("ex.getMessage()"); 
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        try { 
            is.close(); 
            is = null; 
            con.close(); 
            con = null; 
            Dialog.inform("8"); 
        } 
        catch(Exception e){
            Dialog.inform("e"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The application hangs on the con.getReponse() call.  It is running on the blackberry 9800 simulator.  Any help would be super appreciated because I am very stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James, I'm assuming after you turned the MDS Simulator on, you discovered that you also had a problem because you never opened the connection?

Anyway just to give a final working solution:

```
    HttpConnection con = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        String url = new String("http://myserver.com/index.html");

        //I added these two lines to your code and tested it with my own server and got a 200 RC.
        net.rim.device.api.io.transport.ConnectionFactory cf = new net.rim.device.api.io.transport.ConnectionFactory();
        con = (HttpConnection)cf.getConnection(url).getConnection();

        System.out.println(con.toString());
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("3 responseCode = " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            System.out.println("3.5");
            System.out.println(responseCode);
        }
```

Also if you have to support BBJava 5.0 minus, you can have a look at : http://www.versatilemonkey.com/HttpConnectionFactory.java . It's not prefect but its a good place to start with creating connections for pre 5.0 platforms.

Comment: Thanks, ya I forgot to mention that part

Answer (score 2):

getResponseCode() shouldn't be causing it to get stuck, as it simply reads the response that it got after making the connection. My guess is its actually the connection attempt that is hanging. If you're developing for 5.0 or higher, take a look at the [ConnectionFactory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html) class to make sure your connection is being created properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Might help somebody else but actually my solution was elsewhere. In eclipse, I had to go to run>debugconfigurations>simulator>and check "Launch Mobile Data System Simulator.  I find it bizarre that this is not checked by default but oh well, hopefully this saves somebody more time than I spent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding ;deviceside=true at the very end of the URL? Helped in my case.